# How much stuff can I send to my email@Kindle.com, and for how long will Amazon.com keep it?

Tags: amazon, instapaper, kindle

I often send mobi files to my Kindle using the email and I also use Instapaper to send myself links weekly.

Till now I only used this feature with my Kindle connected to the Wi-Fi. I guess that if it's not connected I'd receive my stuff as soon as I connect my Kindle to my Wi-fi network.

But a few questions arise:

1. How much stuff can be stored in the amazon.com storage before they just drop the data? (I guess they can't have endless storage)
2. For how long will Amazon.com keep my stuff on the server if my Wi-Fi connection won't turn on?

On my account I have the following settings:

- Whispersync turned on.
- Personal Document Archiving NOT enabled.

Comment: Have you asked Amazon or checked their site for this information?

Comment: I checked their site but I couldn't find any information about this. I didn't ask directly to them, though

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that once it's synced to your device, it will be removed from Amazon's servers. In which case, I wouldn't think there was a limit other than how much your Kindle can hold.

Comment: My experience is that the cloud storage lists items under "docs", which is synced.  Slick, but more lock-in.  Amazon can pull the plug, or charge, or whatever, whenever they like.  I guess..?